# Provisioning Profile Photos between Microsoft Entra and Slack

Tags: azure-active-directory, slack, provisioning, profile-picture, entra

In order to create a more seamless experience between our different applications for my users, I am trying to provision the users' profile photos from Microsoft Entra into Slack. I already automate the provisioning from Entra to Slack for basic details of the user. However, I have not been able to find a way to smoothly do so with profile photos. Does anyone have any direction? Thanks for any help!

In going into the "Edit Attribute" settings within the provisioning, there is not an attribute for a photo on the Entra side. On the Slack side, there "photos[type eq "photo"].value" attribute that I can push the values into but I am coming up empty.